# How should I get a div's content like this using dom in php?

Tags: php, dom

The div is like this

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;color:#Black;" id="content">
this is text, severaltags
</div>
```

how should i get the div's content including the 
 tags using dom in php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php has some good examples

Comment: domxpath, or regular expression

Comment: **div's content** or div having `id=content`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your using PHP5 you can use `DOMDocument` -- take note that this doesn't provide simple means for retrieving inner html of an element. You can do something along the following:

```
function DOMinnerHTML($element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children = $element->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
    } 
    return $innerHTML; 
} 

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
if ($items->length)
{
    $innerHTML = DOMinnerHTML($items->item(0));
}

echo $innerHTML;
```

For something this simple, although I don't normally recommend it, I'd use regex:

```
preg_match('|<div[^>]+>(.*?)</div>|is', $html, $match);

if ($match)
{
    echo 'html is: ' . $match[1][0];
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. In your DOMinnerHTML function, you could use the ownerDocument(associated DOMDocument Object) property that is already defined for every DOMNode and DOMElement objects. i.e. you could just put in your foreach loop : `$innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );` [source](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domelement.php#101243)

Comment: Nice katsuo! Didn't know about ownerDocument

Comment: yeah! it's pretty handy! That's why I wanted to mention it here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);

$element = $document->getElementById('content');
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the values, you can try something like this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('link-t0-html-file.php');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$element = $xpath->query("//*[@id='content']")->item(0);
echo $element->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you want this

```
echo "< div style='width:90%;margin:0 auto;color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;' 
id='content'>";

echo "this is text, several `<br/>` tags";

echo "< /div>";
```

just mind it never use double quote (") within double quote ("). use single quote(') within double quote.