# how to extract specific span content from webpage

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, curl

I am looking to scrape some content of webpages.

I have the following code but it does not work on every page.

```
$url1 = 'http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-tomyumgoong/menu';
$url2 = 'http://www.just-eat.co.uk/';

$curl = curl_init($url1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
  echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
  exit;
}
echo $page;
curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="responsive-header-logo">(.*?)<\/div>/s';
if (preg_match($regex, $page, $list))
  echo $list[0];
else 
  print "Not found";
```

`$url1` is not working, but when I use `$url2` it works like charm.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: going to else condition "Not Found";

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying the regex to just:

```
$regex = '/responsive-header-logo/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `/<div class="responsive-header-logo">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/`.

Dot matches any character except line break, `[\s\S]` matches any character + line breaks.

For regex testing I'd recommend http://regexr.com/ - this example working: http://regexr.com/3b56u

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you [shouldn't use regex to parse HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/55075).

Instead, you should use libraries which are designed for it. So either [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Example using DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "responsive-header-logo";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

Then use `$dom->saveHTML` to extract the HTML code.

See: [How should I get a div's content like this using dom in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5868480/55075)